# Correct "polymorphic" way to store an enum and sometimes some data

Tags: c++, oop

I'm working on a program for which I store an `std::vector` of points, I also load an `std::unordered_map` of "constraints" for some of these points, and then apply it to the array of points. Currently the constraints are of the form:

```
+---------------+
|Type    |Value |
+---------------+
|Constant|  1.0 |
|        |      |
|Lerp    |  n/a |
|        |      |
|Loop    |  n/a |
|        |      |
|...     |      |
+--------+------+
```

There are several types, but only one of them (Constant) actually needs to store a value (in this case a double). In the prototype I chose to store the value for all of the types and just used a `std::pair<ConstraintType, double>`. It works, but it feels bad; while Constant is the most common point type and storing even a few thousand unused doubles is fairly negligible on modern hardware I don't like the wastefulness. I can't however think of a better way of doing it. If I derive from a base class, as far as I can see, I'm going to end up with a base class with a single virtual method (what's your derived type?) and then if it's constant I downcast it and get the value. Yuck. The only other idea I'm thinking of is just to hold the constants in a separate `std::unordered_map`, but what then do I do if I add another constraint that requires a value (or two)? It doesn't seem to scale.

I'm surely missing something here, this sort of thing should be trivial. Advice would be gratefully accepted (I'm sure it will be a headdesk moment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the polymorphic class as a pointer (unique_ptr for example), but then you don't gain much (as there will then be 4 or 8 B for pointer and another 4-8 B pointer to the virtual table, so at least extra 8 B on 32-bit app which is the same as to store the double every time, and it will be slower then).

As for the check, you can do that without downcasting by providing a (pure) virtual bool check(const Point &) method or similar, which will polymorphically check the constraint (so the constraint type can contain anything and will be checked appropriately).

I was also thinking that you could use boost::any or boost::variant, but that unfortunately wouldn't help much. boost::any uses type erasure to hold the type, so there is a pointer to a virtual holder inside (which again has a pointer to virtual table).

boost::variant requires to know all the types upfront, which might be applicable here. However the storage inside the boost::variant must be as big as the largest type it can hold (so no improvement, as each instance would basically require the same space as the largest constraint storing the double). However, one advantage of boost::variant would be that the check can be done without virtual runtime dispatch, by using boost::static_visitor, so it is faster then.

In general, to really save the maximum amount of space, I don't see any better option than to keep the different constraint types (according to size) in different lists. Second best option is IMHO to use boost::variant, but with pointers (the particular constrain types do not need to be polymorphic then, so you save the space needed for the pointer to the virtual table).

Comment: Clean code is my top priority, since inexperienced devs are on the project and this is not used in tight loop. The virtual probably is the way to go.

Comment: Then yes, the pointer to polymorphic class approach will be the easiest and most understandable. With boost::variant it's a lot about templates, so it is then less clear what is happening there (although it is not terribly difficult).

Comment: I would recommend going with what you have already, i.e. `pair<enum,double>`. It is readable, just as efficient memory wise and faster access wise. Polymorphism would only be useful if there was *another* value field you needed to store for a different enum.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about memory usage, one possibility (not terribly recommended) is to just have a `double` (no `pair`) and enumerate the everything else with a few very rare double constants. For example,

```
const double Lerp = -9e+200;
const double Loop = -9e+201;
```

and everything else that is not `Lerp` or `Loop` is the actual double value.

You can look up the definition of IEEE floats to pick numbers so far near the edge of reality that they will never come up in practice. If they do, you should question your algorithm and whether it should produce values over a googol.

Of course, if you are concerned about space, use `float` instead. It's probably good enough for input data (internally, use `double` for calculations of course).

If you add anything to the double, like a real `enum`, even just a byte, you will unalign all of your data, and either pay with performance misses or padding your structure with extra bytes, so that the `double` value field gets aligned.

Comment: If my primary focus was memory then this would certainly be a good option. I am, however, working with some inexperienced coders on this and so the reason I wanted to ask SO is because I'm trying to demonstrate proper development practices. I expect this solution is the most efficient, however I don't feel that it teaches them about readability first (especially as this is not used inside a tight loop).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd opt for the classes with a virtual function, as described by **[axalis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1274747/axalis)**: it's a clean object oriented design that is easily maintenanble and extensible, for example if you want to add a new type of constraints.

**For the records only:** there could be another way of doing it, using functors and bindings or lambdas:

```
map< Point, function<bool(Point&)>> cst;   // your map
cst [p1] = check_Lerp;                     // predefined function
cst [p2] = bind(check_Constant, _1, 2.0);  // fixing a parameter to have only one free parameter left
cst [p3] = [](Point& p){ return check_Constant(p,2.0); }; // using lambda for more complex constraints
```

To check compliance of the vector, you'd do:

```
if (all_of(v.begin(), v.end(), 
         [&](Point&p) { if (cst.find(p)==cst.end()) return true; else return cst[p](p);}))
    cout<<"everythin is ok"<<endl; 
else cout << "not compliant"<<endl;
```

This is less convenient than a simple table, but it could be an alternative if you'd have many different type of constraints, some being defined on the flow.