# C++ How to create polymorphism container?

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, polymorphism, containers

**following problem**:
We have big grids. In every point we have two fields which have different result arrays.

The first array is 3D. That implies there are three coordinates (i,j,k) and in every point there are five physical data (pressure, density, velocity [x y z]). 
It looks like:

```
Array3D < XXX::LocalFlow < double > > resultarray1;
```

*LocalFlow is a selfmade template class which contains five physical variables.*

The second array is 4D. It is added the frequency (i,j,k,f). There are a lot of frequencies. Every frequency has the same data like the mean flow (first array), but the data type is `complex <double>` here.

```
Array4D < XXX::LocalFlow < std::complex < double > > > resultarray2;
```

**I want to merge the both fields.**

First idea: integrate the first in the second. BUT this is very bad, because I need double memory space (`complex<double>` instead of `double`) in millions of points.

Second idea: Creating a polymorphic container which contains LocalFlow objects with different data types (first double, all the rest complex).

I read a lot about boost::any. Here my question is: Is boost::any just working for simple types like int, float, double or with the own ones too?

Are there other ways to solve my problem?

Comment: How do you want to merge it? Do you just want to store it? Or do you want polymorphic member functions?

Comment: @ThomasFannes I want to have a container instead of Array3D and Array4D which store objects from different type LocalFlow explained above. In the end I just want to have one array and not two like now. What member functions do you need? I want to write in the array (storing) and read from the array in calculating functions.

Comment: Okay, so at runtime you want to be able to write/read points in 3D with associated type XXX::LocalFlow < double >, and points in 3D with associated type XXX::LocalFlow < std::complex < double > >? In the same object?

Comment: Why do you want to merge them?  Can you give a concrete example of how you want to interact with them post-merge?

Comment: @ThomasFannes in 4D! Every point has the coordinates i,j,k and different frequencies f. Every alternative holds five physical values. The values are complex<double>. For f=0 I want to have the mean flow in every point. That implies: I want to have for resultArray(i,j,k,0) the five values from LocalFlow as double!!! Have I explained it better now?

Comment: @Yakk Refactoring the code. We have two fields which are the same in general. The difference is that all higher harmonic (f>0 and f = integer) has complex values. Just the first one has not an imaginary part, so it is better to return a double. My question is now, is it possible to apply an array4D where the first index return a double and all the rest return complex<double>

Comment: @Yakk If yes: We have merge two different fields in our program to one. So it is clearer, simpler and easier to understand

Comment: Just one suggestion: Couldn't you just use `std::complex<double>` and check whether `imag()` is set or not (0.0)?

Comment: @SimonKraemer Do you mean that I check if imag()=0 and if yes, that I have a function which return the double real()? The problem is that we have redundant double memory, because it is also allocated memory for the double imag = 0... Did I understand right yours?

Comment: @D.Mogwitz Having a variant/any storing those two types won't let you merge two fields into one, because one is stored in a 3d and the other in a 4d array.  Again, please provide an actual concrete use case of how you imagine the "merged" types are going to be acted upon.  Is it the case that when frequency is zero, the first array is a subset of the second?  Are i j k dimensions identical in size between the two arrays?  How big is the f dimension?  Are the resultArray1 values used orders of magnitude more often than the resultArray2 values?

Comment: @D.Mogwitz I was thinking about something like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bf387e3c38c036e . Yet the memory might be an issue as a `complex<double>` stores 2 double values.

Comment: @Yakk Okay, I try it again. Visualize a cube! In this cube we put a grid. The grid has millions of points. Every point has different coordinates i, j and k (3D). The mean flow is given every time (invocation: flowfield(i,j,k) - you get the 1st array). In addition we can have (if it wanted for calculation) a lot of frequencies in every point. Now we have 4D (invocation: soundFieldCmplx(i,j,k,f) - you geht the 2nd array). Now it is important to speak about LocalFlow (contains 5 physical data). LocalFlow is a template class.The result array from flowField(i,j,k) has objects from LocalFlow<double>

Comment: @Yakk the result array from soundFieldCmplx(i,j,k,f) has objects from LocalFlow<complex<double>>. Remember: f=0 is mean flow!!! But the mean flow is here a complex<double> too, but it has not an imag() part. What do I want to do? I want to have just one function with one resultarray, where can I store the meanflow on the first place with LocalFlow<double> (5 double values) and all the rest of the array is LocalFlow<complex<double>> (5 complex values).

Comment: Unanswered: How big is the f dimension? Are the resultArray1 values used orders of magnitude more often than the resultArray2 values?

Comment: @Yakk It is different and depends on the case. Average we have 4-5 frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [boost variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/variant.html), as you have a not a lot different of types you want to store (2). Especially with the visitor pattern, this make reading/writing/altering the data easily.

Another solution is, as far as I understand the problem, creating a threedimensional grid where the element is something like:

```
struct type
{
    XXX::LocalFlow < double > mean_element;
    XXX::LocalFlow < std::complex<double> > * f_values_array;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! If I understood boost variant right, so it can store just one element simultaneously because it is an union? I want to store all results in the array, so it does not work for me. but the second is very interesting and looks good. Can I apply the array like this: Array4D<struct type> resultarray ? So I have in the struct the different elements... yeah this looks nice

Comment: You could have array of boost::variant<LocalFlow<double>, LocalFlow<complex<double> > >. However, as I mentioned in my answer, that is no big advantage over joining the two types, because boost::variant storage is as big as the biggest type it can hold, so it would still allocate memory for two doubles despite only one double being actually used in the particular variant instance.

Comment: @axalis Now I am understanding the solution with boost variant. Thanks! But I have still the same problem how you explained, right? So I allocate also the same memory for the double as a complex<double>?

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems that using boost::any is a bit of an overkill, since in essence, boost::any is a "safer" way to use a generic type of void*.

As @ThomasFannes suggested, boost::variant is an option, since it proposes to perform static polymorphism in an elegant, quite easy-to-read way.

However, for the sake of variety, I would suggest another option.

First let us define a `GenericLocalFlow` structure that will bear either a `LocalFlow<double>` or a `LocalFlow<std::complex<double>>` using, for instance, the `boost::optional` class. The actual type being stored this generic class is determined at construction time. An implementation of this class could read

```
class GenericLocalFlow {

  // Here, you could define constructors that fit your needs...
  // ...

  boost::optional<LocalFlow<double>>& asScalar();
  boost::optional<LocalFlow<std::complex<double>>>& asComplex();

};
```

Remark that the member functions are not `const` for read/write purposes. Also, upon calling either member function you can query if the scalar or the complex version of the structure has been initialised.

Then, I suggest you store the complete data set in

```
Array3D<std::vector<GenericLocalFlow>> results;
```

The std::vector accounting for the fourth dimension, i.e. the frequencies.

Comment: I just realised that the proposed option is very similar to the one @ThomasFannes detailed earlier... Sorry for that ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The best two possibilities IMHO are:

1. Create custom vector which will hold each type separately, with two separate vectors under the hood.
2. Create base class for the two and use (runtime) polymorphism through virtual classes. Then you of course need to not store the objects directly, but pointers to them (however, then you need additional two pointers per each value, that might be easily bigger than the size of additional double, and those two pointers would actually be needed for the complex<> type as well in addition).

boost::any is principally the same as the solution 2. - it uses type erasure under the hood, so two extra pointers per instance as well (pointer to the type-erased holder and pointer to its virtual table). With the "bonus" that you will need to typecast everything back and forth to the correct types.

With the boost::variant you do not have the extra pointers for virtuals, but unfortunately the boost::variant storage must (obviously) be as big as the biggest type it can hold (so no improvement over merging the types directly, regarding the memory usage).

See my answer to similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35003245/1274747

The option 1. above has also the advantage that you can then iterate the different kinds separately, which is better for CPU cache behavior (and that is especially true for polymorphic classes with virtual methods, that is why game programmers sometimes sort the collections of polymorphic game objects according to the actual type, to iterate the various types in a block and thus not trash the instruction cache - so even in case 2. you actually might want to sort them according to the different types).

Answer (score 0):

Do not do this.  Just store the array of complex numbers.

If f is medium in size (say 50-100), shaving  double off the size of 1 array in a lesser dimension saves 0.5% memory.

Any type safe variant on the element is going to use way more than this.  We are talking 20%-100% memory overhead and possibly serious runtime costs.

A 3 dimensional array of `double, array<complex<double>>` where the first is the "`f=0`" and the array is the frequency data does shave the 0.5% (well, frequency-count/200), at the cost of code complexity and slower access (due to branches).

Unless the number of frequencies is small, or you access the f=0 data orders of magnitude more often (so cache hits are better with compact data), or you have nothing better to do than tiny optimizations, your plan does not look like a good idea.